# dotnet build not able to find nuget package in custom source while Visual Studio manage it

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

In a big .Net Solution, we are using a lot of nugets.
We have three nuget sources:

1. nuget.org
2. Our azure dev artifact repository with a custom babelFor package(compiled with our license)
3. A custom DevExpress repository with a specific token.

In Visual Studio, everything worked, I even cleared the nuget packages, rebuild, everything is being restore properly.

But if I run(for code analysis purpose):

`dotnet build Solution/MySolution.sln --no-incremental`

I receive an error that it doesn't manage to find the package for babel:

```
D:\VS1\XXX\YYY.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Babel.Obfuscator. No packages exist with this id in source(s): DevExpress, DevExpress 19.1 Local, DevExpress 19.2 Local, DevExpress 20.2 Local, DevExpress 21.1 Local, DevExpress 21.2 Local, DevExpress 22.1 Local, DevExpress 22.2 Local, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline
 Packages, nuget.org [D:\VS1\XXX\MySolution.sln]
```

My packages are properly configured:

[image]

But it seems it doesn't try to use the Azure Devop artifact repository(Babel3)(which will require some sort of authentication).

So I'm guessing that it wasn't able to authenticate? How can I provide such authentication to `dotnet build`?

**EDIT**
Apparently, I've a nuget.config file at the same place than my `.sln` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Babel3" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/XXXX/_packaging/Babel3/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="Devexpress" value="https://nuget.devexpress.com/YYYY/api" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="packages\" />
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="packages\" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

I'm just wondering if the issue could be that my SLN file is not at the root repository, and that I'm doing a `dotnet build Solution/MySolution.sln`

**EDIT 2**

If i try to run:

```
dotnet restore Solution/MySolution.sln --configfile Solution/nuget.config
```

I do get an error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\NuGet.targets(156,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [D:\VS1\Solution\MySolution.sln]
```

How can I provide some identity/token when doing restore?

Answer (score 1):

That Nuget config is for Visual Studio, it doesn't not necessarily get used by the `dotnet` command line. I find the safest way to do this is to include a [`nuget.config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file) file with your solution. That way it is source controlled and everyone get the same setup when they clone your project. Simply create the file and drop it in the root of your solution, for example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="Babel3" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/....../nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="DevExpress" value="https://nuget.devexpress.com/....." />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

See here for more ways to configure the package sources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior

Comment: Great, I will look into it. The weird thing is that azure Devop is able to build everything using DotNetBuild. Do you know where this file should be located ? Is it at the root location or at the same place than the `sln` file ?(my sln is not at the root)

Comment: DevOps can also have it's own Nuget config, check in there

Comment: Apparently, I already have a nuget.config just near the `sln` file, is there a way to specify the path of the nuget.config to use?

Comment: Have you tried running the `dotnet build` command from inside the solution folder? Alternatively, I think you can use `dotnet build --configfile path/to/nuget.config Solution/MySolution.sln`

Comment: Yes, same result inside the solution folder. It goes farther with the configfile, but then I get an auth error 

Comment: So my answer is correct, if you specify the config file, it is working. The auth is another problem entirely.

Comment: I disagree, I'm still not sure that my existing nuget.config was not taken into account. I said in my initial question I tought the issue was related to authentication

Comment: If your nuget.config file was being used, you would see an auth error, but you don't. If you fix the auth error, then you still won't be able to use the command line as mentioned in the question. Can you try adding `--interactive` as well as `--configfile`?